# Laravel 5 bilingual Product model

Tags: laravel-5, model, multilingual

I am looking for the most straightaway solution and breaking my head about implementing a bilingual Product model with only one basic requirements: the product query should only deliver results where the product name in the app()->locale language is set.

I'm stuck right at the beginning to decide wether I should keep completely different models (Product_en and Product_es), this would make querying easiest I guess, or have just one Product model with the English texts, with hasOne() methods pointing to the Spanish translations? In the latter case, how would I effectively query for entries which have translations?

Thanks a lot for any hints. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a `language` property for the `Product` model and would add a [Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes) for this, where you can filter the results with the value of `App::getLocale()`.

This way, any time you just query the product, you get the `Product` models on the actually selected language.

Comment: Köszönöm Zoli, this one is very useful for me! :-)

Comment: Szivesen! Glad that helped :)